# Exclude non-matching strings from data frame

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames `DFA` and `DFB` with a common ID column `ID3`. I want to identify the ID3's which are present in DFA but missing from DFB. I then want to merge DFA and DFB together, but keeping only the common ID3's.

DFA:

| Time | Day | Month | Year | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 13_12_12_23 |
| 12 | 9 | 9 | 91 | 12_9_9_91 |
| 10 | 2 | 3 | 80 | 10_2_3_80 |

DFB:

| First | Last | Age | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Smith | 25 | 13_12_12_23 |
| Phil | Green | 41 | 6_11_8_45 |
| Joe | Bloggs | 71 | 12_9_9_91 |
| Ben | Bolton | 84 | 2_1_9_63 |
| Kate | Jones | 34 | 10_2_3_80 |

Intended result:

| ID3 | Time | Day | Month | Year | First | Last | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13_12_12_23 | 13 | 12 | 12 | 23 | Tom | Smith | 25 |
| 12_9_9_91 | 12 | 9 | 9 | 91 | Joe | Bloggs | 71 |
| 10_2_3_80 | 10 | 2 | 3 | 80 | Kate | Jones | 34 |

I have tried the following, which doesn't seem to be identifying the different ID2's correctly

`DIFFERENT_IDS <-anti_join(DFA, DFB, by = "ID2")`

`my_ID2_N <- as.vector(unlist(DIFFERENT_IDS$ID2))`

`DFA1 <- DFA`

`DFA1 <-DFA1[!(DFA1$ID2 %in% my_ID2_N),]`

Any suggestions of where I might be going wrong? It is probably worth noting too that the actual data frames I am merging contain different numbers of rows within each of the ID2 (so we have ID2's listed multiple times for each trial sometimes, depending on the data points being reported, so perhaps this is causing the issue?)

Comment: @RYann left_join has worked here - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really provide a reproducible code next time...
Let me know if that did the trick. I used left join to keep only the matching ID's from from DFB
use `library(data.pasta)` to have the greatest addin possible in R (`esquisse` is also nice)

```
DFA <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Time = c(13L, 12L, 10L),
               Day = c(12L, 9L, 2L),
             Month = c(12L, 9L, 3L),
              Year = c(23L, 91L, 80L),
               ID3 = c("13_12_12_23", "12_9_9_91", "10_2_3_80")
       )

DFB <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             First = c("Tom", "Phil", "Joe", "Ben", "Kate"),
              Last = c("Smith", "Green", "Bloggs", "Bolton", "Jones"),
               Age = c(25L, 41L, 71L, 84L, 34L),
                      ID3 = c("13_12_12_23",
                              "6_11_8_45","12_9_9_91","2_1_9_63","10_2_3_80")
       )

left_join(DFA,DFB) %>% 
  relocate(ID3, .before = everything())

          ID3 Time Day Month Year First   Last Age
1 13_12_12_23   13  12    12   23   Tom  Smith  25
2   12_9_9_91   12   9     9   91   Joe Bloggs  71
3   10_2_3_80   10   2     3   80  Kate  Jones  34
```